# Why is my EditText not editable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

Why is my EditText not editable?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:weightSum="2"
tools:context="com.example.musicvideomaker.ProjectSettingsX"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Project Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I run the app in the emulator and I can't change the EditText. The keyboard doesn't appear when I touch it. I have tried it on multiple emulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think its a code problem. I think its got something to do with the emulator itself. Avds are usually made to use input from your computer's physical keyboard, so try just typing on it, if you dont want to do that. 
Go to AVD manager, click on your device, and click on edit.
See this:
Check/uncheck it as per your need.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your EditText is editable, but your emulator probably doesn't have keyboard support.  You will need to edit the AVD to add an option as follows:

- From Eclipse, Go to AVD Mananger.
- Select the particular AVD and click on Edit
- Go to the Hardware section, click on New.
- Select the Property Name : Keyboard Support
  By default, it is added with a value of 'no'. Just click on the value column and change it to 'yes'.
- Click on Edit AVD again.

This will add a property `hw.keyboard=yes` in config.ini file for the AVD. And it should work fine from there.

Comment: I'm sure you know what you're doing, but I do not see those options. It might be because I'm running Mac, I'm not sure. When I go to edit, I see that I can change AVD Name, Device, Target, CPU disabled, Keyboard: Hardware keyboard present checkbox, Camera, Memory options, interal storage, SD card, Emulation Option: Snapshot and Use Host GPU checkboxes, another checkbox disabled for overriding existing AVD with same name.  I do not see a hardware section.

Comment: I'm glad the other post helped you out.  This could be a difference in the version of android tools we're using.